# No reproduce una animacion en Android

Tags: android-studio, animación

Estoy intentando hacer una animacion para una imagen, pero el problema es que la animacion no se esta ejecutando, no muestra ningun error, coloque mi imagen que quiero animar en una clase que extiende de **Fragment**.

Esta es mi clase que extiende de Fragment:

```
public class animacionesFrgmento extends Fragment {

    public FloatingActionButton reproductor;

    public  animacionesFrgmento(){

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_animaciones, container, false);
        reproductor = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        reproductor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PlayAnimation(view);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void PlayAnimation(View view){

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Reproduciendo animacion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ImageView esfera = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.esfera);
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.animation_esfera);
        animatorSet.setTarget(esfera);
        animatorSet.start();

    }
}
```

Este es mi archivo de animacion XML, esta en una carpeta que se llama **"animator"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set android:ordering="together" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:duration="400"
        android:valueTo="500"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="y"
        android:duration="400"
        android:valueTo="500"/>

</set>
```

Este es mi archivo donde tengo mi boton flotante y mi ImageView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/esfera"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/esfera" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Estoy imprimiendo un Toast en mi metodo donde intento ejecutar la
>   animacion y el mensaje si se muestra, pero la animacion no hace nada,
>   el emulador donde corro el proyecto es un emulador con API 25

Comment: Que tipo de animación deseas realizar?

Comment: @Jorgesys Quiero hacer una animacion de escala y que gire mi imagen, estoy intentado mover la imagen en el eje x y luego al eje y, para probar

Comment: Lo que buscas es lo que se ejecute tu animación?

Comment: @A.Palacio si, pero nose por que no se ejecuta, quiero animar una imagen que tengo en un Fragmento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo en tu código no esta encontrando la referencia de `ImageView` solo se esta inflando el `Layout`, para ello debes declarar una variable `ImageView` como lo hiciste con `FloatingActionButton` y despues referenciarlo dentro del `onCreateView`.

Codigo:

```
public class animacionesFrgmento extends Fragment {

    public FloatingActionButton reproductor;
    public ImageView esfera;
    public  animacionesFrgmento(){

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_animaciones, container, false);
esfera = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.esfera);
        reproductor = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        reproductor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PlayAnimation(view);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void PlayAnimation(View view){

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Reproduciendo animacion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        AnimatorSet animatorSet = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.animation_esfera);
        animatorSet.setTarget(esfera);
        animatorSet.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes razon, no me di cuenta de ese detalle, muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, excelente tarde.